# Include Twig with multiple parameters

Tags: arrays, parameters, include, twig

#### Is there a way to include a Twig-template with more than one parameter?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

The following Twig is rendered by my Symfony Controller:

```
{% for object in objects %}
        {% if object.type == "simple" %}
               {% include 'BBLWebBundle:content:simple.html.twig' 
                with [{'picture': object.picture}, {'link': object.link}, {'name': object.name}, {'info': object.info}] %}

        {% elseif object.type == "mp3" %}
                {% include 'BBLWebBundle:content:mp3.html.twig'
                with [{'picture': object.picture}, {'link': object.link}, {'name': object.name}, {'info': object.info}] %}

        {% elseif object.type == "video" %}
                {% include 'BBLWebBundle:content:video.html.twig' 
                with [{'picture': object.picture}, {'link': object.link}, {'name': object.name}, {'info': object.info}] %}
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The Controller also passes some parameters (this is just some Dummy-Data):

```
    $objects['ob1']['type'] = "simple";
    $objects['ob1']['picture'] = "this is a picture";
    $objects['ob1']['link'] = "#";
    $objects['ob1']['info'] = "Oh wooow some Info";
    $objects['ob1']['name'] = "Potato";
    return $this->render('BBLWebBundle:Base:content.html.twig',
            array('objects' => $objects, 'title' => "Im very cool Title"));
```

This is one Twig-template which should be included:

```
<div>{{ picture }}</div> 
<div><a href="{{ link }}"> <h3>{{ name }}</h3></a><br />{{ info }}<br /></div>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's easier than you think:

```
{% include 'BBLWebBundle:content:simple.html.twig' 
     with {'picture': object.picture, 'link': object.link, 'name': object.name, 'info': object.info} %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, it really was easier than i thought.

Comment: What if `object.picture` or `object.link` is null? How do I pass `` value if it is null?

Answer (score 3):

Now it's four years later and now you can include a list of templates

So you could change the above code from

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {% if object.type == "simple" %}
        {% include 'BBLWebBundle:content:simple.html.twig' 
            with [{'picture': object.picture}, {'link': object.link}, {'name': object.name}, {'info': object.info}] %}

    {% elseif object.type == "mp3" %}
        {% include 'BBLWebBundle:content:mp3.html.twig'
            with [{'picture': object.picture}, {'link': object.link}, {'name': object.name}, {'info': object.info}] %}

    {% elseif object.type == "video" %}
        {% include 'BBLWebBundle:content:video.html.twig' 
            with [{'picture': object.picture}, {'link': object.link}, {'name': object.name}, {'info': object.info}] %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

to an almost one liner doing exactly the same as simple as this:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {% include 'BBLWebBundle:content:' ~ object.type ~ '.html.twig' 
            with [{'picture': object.picture}, {'link': object.link}, {'name': object.name}, {'info': object.info}] %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now imagine you don't have a template for every `object.type` all you have to do is add the path to a "default" template to the list like:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {% include
        [
            'BBLWebBundle:content:' ~ object.type ~ '.html.twig',
            'BBLWebBundle:content:default.html.twig'
        ]    with [{'picture': object.picture}, {'link': object.link}, {'name': object.name}, {'info': object.info}] %}
{% endfor %}
```

So like this if `object.type.html.twig` can not be found it will just use the `defualt.html.twig`. It will use the first one gets found from the list. [More information can be found here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/include.html)