# Passing an array to an include in twig

Tags: php, twig, twig-extension

Seems like the argument is not passed properly ...

```
    {% set items = {
        item: {
            'id': '1',
            'brand': 'client1',
            'description': 'solutions.client1.description' | trans},
        item: {
            'id':  '2',
            'brand': 'client2',
            'description': 'solutions.client2.description' | trans}
    } %}

    {% include 'site/case-excerpt.html.twig'
        with {'id': items.item.id,
              'brand': items.item.brand,
              'description': items.item.description
        }
  %}
```

Then in the `site/case-excerpt.html.twig` file :

```
{% include 'site/testimonials/item.html.twig'
     with {'id': id,
           'brand': brand,
           'description': description
          }
%}
```

And in the `site/testimonials/item.html.twig` file:

```
<div class="carousel-item {{ id }}">
    <img src="images/brands/{{ brand }}.jpg">
    <p>
        {{ description }}
    </p>
</div>
```

The expected output would be the following :

```
<div class="carousel-item 1">
    <img src="images/brands/client1.jpg">
    <p>
        I'm the content of the translation for the first client
    </p>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item 2">
    <img src="images/brands/client2.jpg">
    <p>
        I'm the content of the translation for the second client
    </p>
</div>
```

I dropped the idea of looping manually trough `items` since it seems to be possible to have it done nicely, [here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019887/include-twig-with-multiple-parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the final working code

Base file. Array is defined and passed to the include.

```
    {% set items = [{
            'id': '1',
            'brand': 'euromaster',
            'description': 'solutions.euromaster.description' | trans},
        {
            'id':  '2',
            'brand': 'logo-havas-voyages',
            'description': 'solutions.havas.description' | trans}
    ] %}

    {% include 'site/case-excerpt.html.twig'
        with {'items': items
        }
    %}
```

Then in the `site/case-excerpt.html.twig` file :
We loop on the array and include the partial

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% include 'site/testimonials/item.html.twig'
         with {'id': item.id,
               'brand': item.brand,
               'description': item.description
              }
    %}
{% endfor %}
```

And in the `site/testimonials/item.html.twig` file:

```
<div class="carousel-item {{ id }}">
    <img src="images/brands/{{ brand }}.jpg">
    <p>
        {{ description }}
    </p>
</div>
```

Thanks @Mazzy !

Comment: I came across this same situation, where I think it would be even better to set `with item` in the second file, instead of listing the same properties again.

Answer (score 4):

In the example you provided, they loop through the objects, and include a partial for every object.

You are using `items.item`.
Twig has no clue what you want, also, creating an array with the same key `item`, won't work

```
{% set items = [{
            'id': '1',
            'brand': 'client1',
            'description': 'solutions.client1.description' | trans},
            {
            'id':  '2',
            'brand': 'client2',
            'description': 'solutions.client2.description' | trans}
    ] %}
```

then loop through your items and include the partial

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% include 'site/case-excerpt.html.twig'
            with {'id': item.id,
                  'brand': item.brand,
                  'description': item.description
            }
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mazzy, I'm sure it's a big step forward, however I'm still stuck because I have 3 different files, not two. 

I'd like to 
1. Base file. Define the array and pass it in an include to the `case-excerpt.html.twig` file
2. `case-excerpt.html.twig` : loop through the array to show `item.html.twig` as templating
3. `item.html.twig` display the content of the current array value

Does it make esnse to you ?

Comment: Got it. I'm going to publish the final result, thanks !